# List Available Templates for Current Theme in a Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I am new to Wordpress as of last week and am having trouble understanding some things.  I have created a plugin that allows for the dynamic creation of multiple pages.

There is one thing that I cannot figure out how to do.  I want to display a list of the available templates in a dropdown, so that the user an assign that particular template to the pages they are creating.

Is there a wordpress function built in that allows for this.  If not, can anyone guide me towards where to start on this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available templates are returned by [`get_page_templates()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_page_templates/), which mostly forwards it to current theme's object.

There is also more specialized [`page_template_dropdown()`](http://queryposts.com/function/page_template_dropdown/), which you might be able to use in your form.

Comment: My hero.  Thank you so much.  Sorry for not being able to upvote due to insufficient rep.